# Unsampled GA data in R

Tags: r, google-analytics

I am attempting to extract unsampled data for the past nine months. The website is pretty active, and as such, I'm unable to get the data in its entirety (over 3 m rows) unsampled. I'm currently attempting to break out the filtering so that I'm only returning under 10k rows at a time (which is the API response limit). Is there a way I can loop over a number of days? I tried using the batch function with no success. I have included my code for reference, I was thinking of writing a loop and doing it in 10 day intervals? I appreciate any input.

Thanks!

```
library(RGA)

gaData <- get_ga(id, start.date = start_date, 
                 end.date= "today" , metrics = "ga:sessions",
                 dimensions = "ga:date, ga:medium, ga:country, ga:hour, ga:minute", 
                 filters = "ga:country==United States;ga:medium==organic",
                 max.results = NULL,
                 batch = TRUE,
                 sort = "ga:date")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_ga` function havn't `batch` param (see `?get_ga`). Try it with the `fetch.by` option. You could test a different variants: "month", "week", "day".

```
library(RGA)
authorize()
gaData <- get_ga(id, start.date = start_date, 
                 end.date= "today" , metrics = "ga:sessions",
                 dimensions = "ga:date, ga:medium, ga:country, ga:hour, ga:minute", 
                 filters = "ga:country==United States;ga:medium==organic",
                 sort = "ga:date", fetch.by = "week")
```